# How to make histverify ignore "!!"?

Tags: bash

Is it possible to make `shopt -s histverify` ignore `!!` (execute it without verifying) but still verify other history expansions, such as `!rm` ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume not. However, you could create an alias for the previous history command using `fc`. Example with pc for "previous command"

```
alias pc='fc -s 9999999'
```

You could actually grep history to find the current history number, which would be more correct. if the number is too large for the history, fc just uses the highest history number available, which would be the number of the previous command. I'm assuming you'll never hit a history number that high so it should just work.

Comment: the command help notes that running `fc -s` with no other arguments will re-execute the last command, so no need for the hack.